# Filling tank "Heavy duty Coolant" or "Coolant Mixture with Water"

Tags: engine, coolant, hyundai, diesel, antifreeze

A newbie into car world here. I have a 2016 Hyundai i20 1.4L Diesel. I have found various opinions regarding the coolant/antifreeze liquid that we use in the vehicle. Some believe 1:4 mixture of coolant with water can be a disaster, OEM just need you to buy new vehicles and they suggest something that brings the car to a mechanic shed more often. Others believe that's absolutely fine. While few others believe in using RTU (Ready to use) antifreeze agents which don't have to be mixed with water and can be filled directly and fully. Few believe gasket can catch rust and allow water/coolant into the engine and make things bad.

I would like to understand what is a better choice for a vehicle that might travel around 800kms a day (of course with short breaks) or even for a normal scenario. What is the ideal thing that would keep my automotive parts and vehicle healthy. I have seen an engine seize when one of my relative had used water as their coolant when they found the coolant is leaking.

Also what is an ideal replacement schedule for coolant. If you have anymore tips and tricks happy to listen. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between Ready-To-Use coolant and coolant concentrate that you mix yourself with distilled water is cost and convenience. RTU is more expensive but more convenient.

Always mix coolant concentrate with distilled water in a clean container, then fill the coolant tank or radiator from the mixture. Pouring concentrate or distilled water directly into the engine is not recommended because it is prone to errors in mixture.

Do not keep your mixed coolant in a container that can be confused as a beverage. Coolant is deadly poison.

Your owner's manual says that you must use an ethylene glycol coolant mixed with water, and it must be compatible with aluminum engines. Check the coolant label to confirm before you buy it.

The standard coolant mixture is 50% ethylene glycol concentrate and 50% distilled water (or commercial premix) for the best protection from freezing and boiling-over. The corrosion inhibitors in the coolant concentrate are included in an amount that relies on this 50-50 mix concentration. If you use a 1:4 mixture because you do not expect freezing temperatures, you will have less protection from boiling over in hot weather and your corrosion protection will be exhausted in a short time.

Your owner's manual recommends checking the coolant level in the tank at every maintenance interval, such as each oil change, and to check clarity and color. Top up the coolant if the level is low and replace the coolant if it becomes dirty.

Your owner's manual recommends draining and replacing the coolant after 120,000 KM or 10 years, whichever comes first. Then repeat every 120,000 KM or 10 years, whichever comes first.

Helpful tip: When deciding how to care for your car, if you have a choice between several conflicting things that "they say", forget what they say and follow your owner's manual's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks @MTA, the 50-50 mixture sounds good to me. I couldn't find the owner's manual on the internet and I have got this vehicle on the used car market. If you could give me the link for the manual if you have, that would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: @Fayaz Your manual is at: https://www.hyundai.com/content/dam/hyundai/in/en/data/connect-to-service/owners-manual/old/Elite_i20.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will go through it.